# Load Un-clossable Jquery Modal on Page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup, modal-dialog

I am trying to force a user to first fill a form which will be in a un-closable modal and once the user enters the data he can get access to the website.

I am refering to [this example.](http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/#ex5)

-Example 5: the un-closable window

The modal is working exactly the way I want it but I am unable to make it load with the page.

I dont understand Javascript much thus I am stuck here.

I tried using this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function() {                         
$("#ex5").dialog({modal: true});  
});
</script>
```

But this didn't work.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Also please suggest any other un-closable popup modal which I can use instead of the one I have mentioned.

Comment: have you tried .off method?

Comment: @soundhiraraj : What is .off method ? can you please tell me how to use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [jQuery UI Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/), you can add the `no-close` class to the modal dialog to hide the close button.

Also, if your javascript is running too soon with `$(document).ready()`, you could try `$(window).load()`.

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page
>   Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.
>   Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run
>   once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

So you could try something like this, and make sure that there is an element with `id="ex5"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(window).load(function() {                         
    $("#ex5").dialog({modal: true,
                      dialogClass: 'no-close'});  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you Have to code like this, refer this coding,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var outerThis = this, isCloseable = false;
       $('#close-button').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(outerThis.isCloseable) {
                $('#ex5').hide();
                outerThis.isCloseable = false;
            }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to open modal with page load

```
      <script type="text/javascript">                                         

          $(document).ready(function() {       

            $('#ex5').modal('show');                  

          });

       </script>
```

You find the detailed instructions about Bootstrap modal here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals